# Do learning rate scheduler have any significant improvement or redundant on Adam optimizer?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, algorithms, pytorch

As in [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980), Adam optimizer is adaptive learning rates algorithm.

Is learning rate scheduler become redundant when use with Adam and AdamW ?

Is it best practices to use learning rate scheduler with Adam/AdamW ?